# SwiftUI Scaling Carousel Animations Breaking

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, carousel

I'm trying to create a scaling carousel in `SwiftUI`, where the centered item is 1.0 scale and the side items scale down to 80%. Everything works fine if I start at the first item, but when I try to set the `ScrollView` to the center item, the paging breaks. I've tried a few work arounds such as setting the initial middle index in `onAppear` instead of the view model, using a `task` for a delay, and using animations for both of those scenarios. Neither work 100%. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of SwiftUIs current abilities?

[image]

```
struct CarouselView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = CarouselViewModel()
    private let colors: [Color] = [.teal, .blue, .green, .orange, .purple, .red]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: viewModel.spacing) {
                    ForEach(0..<viewModel.maxValue, id: \.self) { i in
                        let v = i % colors.count
                        colors[v]
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                            .aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width - viewModel.spacing * 4)
                            .overlay {
                                Text(i.formatted())
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                            }
                            .visualEffect { [viewModel] content, geometryProxy in
                                content
                                    .scaleEffect(
                                        y: viewModel.yScale(using: geometryProxy)
                                    )
                            }
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .safeAreaPadding(.horizontal, viewModel.spacing * 2)
            .scrollPosition(id: $viewModel.id)
//            .onAppear {
//                viewModel.id = 25
//            }
//            .task {
//                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
//                withAnimation {
//                    viewModel.id = 250
//                }
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@MainActor
final class CarouselViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: Int? // = 250
    let maxValue = 500
    let scale: (max: CGFloat, min: CGFloat) = (1, 0.8)
    let spacing: CGFloat = 12
    
    nonisolated func yScale(using proxy: GeometryProxy) -> Double {
        let itemMidX = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView).midX
        
        guard let scrollViewWidth = proxy.bounds(of: .scrollView)?.width else {
            return 0
        }
        
        let scrollViewMidX = scrollViewWidth / 2
        let distanceFromCenter = abs(scrollViewMidX - itemMidX)
        let itemWidth = proxy.size.width
        let percentageToMidX = 1 - (distanceFromCenter / (itemWidth - spacing))
        let calculatedScale = ((scale.max - scale.min) * percentageToMidX) + scale.min
        return max(scale.min, calculatedScale)
    }
}
```